# Biblatex: Creating categories based on keywords

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

Consider the scenario: I'd like to subdivide the bibliography in my document into subbibliographies. I find the idea of categories particularly appealing. Thus I have annotated my `.bib` files with `keywords`. However, I'm extremely reluctant to add single keys to categories. To do this, I'd have to reference every citation twice: once in the `\cite` command and once more in the preamble of the document with `\addtocategory`. This seems redundant and also very risky in case I forget one or the other.

Since the category information is already present in the `.bib` files, is it possible to add items to a category via keywords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On first glance what you describe sounds like you want to filter your bibliography with `keyword`/`notkeyword` directly.

Categories are supposed to offer a way to categories your bibliography dynamically from within the current document, keywords are supposed to be static and attach to an entry in the `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{aristotle:anima,
  author       = {Aristotle},
  title        = {De Anima},
  date         = 1907,
  editor       = {Hicks, Robert Drew},
  publisher    = {Cambridge University Press},
  location     = {Cambridge},
  keywords     = {primary},
}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
  keywords     = {secondary},
}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,aristotle:anima,nussbaum}
\printbibliography[keyword=primary, title=Primary Sources]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary, title=Secondary Sources]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=primary,notkeyword=secondary]
\end{document}
```

It is possible to combine category and keyword filtering options and - if more complex logic is required - in bibliography filters (`\defbibfilter`) or bibliography checks (`\defbibcheck`).

Comment: That is of course a viable solution and if nothing else turns up I'll eventually resort to this. However, I quite like the way biblatex treats categories: The subheadings are very cleanly defined and `\bibbycategory` seems very intriguing. Ideally, I would define the categories in a preamble shared (with `\input`) by several documents. In the individual documents, I'd print the bibliography with `\bibbycategory` and would not even have care which categories are used in the individual documents.